# Problems saving Doctrine2 record with cascade={"persist"}, null PK is attempted inserted event after specifying it explicitly

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, cascade

I have two models, Product and Category. Each product can be part of several categories with a `weight` property. This gives three tables; `product`, `category` and `product_category`. Here are my models:

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="product") **/
class Product
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id = null;

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductCategory", mappedBy="product", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist","remove"}) @var ProductCategory[] **/
    protected $productCategories = null;

    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->productCategories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Take an array of category_ids of which the product should be part of. The first category gets weight=1, next weight=2 etc.
    public function saveCategories ($category_ids)
    {
        $weight = 1;
        $this->productCategories = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($category_ids as $category_id)
            $this->productCategories[] = new ProductCategory($this->id, $category_id, $weight++);
    }
}


/** @Entity @Table(name="category") **/
class Category
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id = null;

    /** @Column(type="string",length=200,nullable=false) @var string **/
    protected $title = null;

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductCategory", mappedBy="category") @var ProductCategory[] **/
    protected $productCategories = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productCategories = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}


/** @Entity @Table(name="product_category") **/
class ProductCategory
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer",nullable=false) **/
    protected $product_id = null;

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer",nullable=false) **/
    protected $attraction_id = null;

    /** @Column(type="integer",nullable=false) **/
    protected $weight = null;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product",inversedBy="productCategories") @JoinColumn(name="product_id",referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE") @var Product **/
    protected $product;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category",inversedBy="productCategories") @JoinColumn(name="category_id",referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE") @var Category **/
    protected $category;

    public function __construct ($product_id, $category_id, $weight)
    {
        $this->product_id = $product_id;
        $this->attraction_id = $attraction_id;
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to save the categories, I get an error message stating that `product_id` cannot be null - and the MySQL log confirms that Doctrine attempts to insert a row into `product_category` with both `product_id` and `category_id` set to 0, despite me setting them in the `ProductCategory` constructor.

Any suggestions where I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. In Doctrine2, there is no such thing as product_id nor category_id. You only deal with Product and Category entities, column values are handled by doctrine itself.

Instead of

```
....
foreach ($category_ids as $category_id)
    $this->productCategories[] = new ProductCategory($this->id, $category_id, $weight++);
```

You should have something like

```
public function saveCategories ($categories)
{
    foreach ($categories as $category)
        $this->productCategories[] = new ProductCategory($this, $category)
```

Fix the constructor of ProductCategory to reflect these and also remove category_id and product_id definitions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have an array of category IDs though (coming via an API) - do I need to fetch each of these categories from the DB first?

Comment: Yes. You can also throw notFoundException if there is no category with some $id.

Comment: Thanks, I got a little further now. Is it always recommended to select the objects from the DB first (with an additional DB query), even when I am sure the IDs are correct?

I got another hindrance in the same area: I figured that orphanRemoval and cascade would make sure that the ProductCategory objects that no longer were associated with the Product would be removed automatically.

However, but with my code above, new ProductCategories are added to the existing ones (throwing an Exception if the PK already exists). Do you know why the ProductCategory objects are not removed like they should?

Comment: Well... it is supposed to work that way. Keep in mind that $this->productcategory[] = ... WILL add new relation, even duplicated. You can either check if it is already related to $category and skip it, or set $array = new ArrayCollection, put $array->add(new ProductCategory) for each category and finish with $this->productcategory = $array.